# How to make make_series group by top of the hour and not on the exact time when query is run

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

The following query gets me sales per hour with 0 for empty hours when no sales exists

```
tilldevicedata
| where todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc) between (_startTime.._endTime)
| where Brand has_any (_brand)
| where Country == _country
| where Store has_any (_store)
| make-series sum(TransactionValueGross) on todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc) from _startTime to _endTime step 1h
```

The problem is that the resulting time stamps are the exact time the query runs like below

```
"TransactionTimeStampUtc": [
    "2022-05-13T07:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T08:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T09:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T10:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T11:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T12:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T13:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T14:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T15:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T16:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T17:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T18:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T19:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T20:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T21:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T22:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-13T23:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-14T00:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-14T01:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-14T02:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-14T03:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-14T04:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-14T05:40:22.0000000Z",
    "2022-05-14T06:40:22.0000000Z"
],
```

I would like it to be on top of the hour so to say at 07:00:00 and 08:00:00 so that everything that falls within that hours ends up on the top of the hour timestamp because the resulting column graph looks off when the values are not exactly on the hour.

Can this be achieved?

[image: column graph]

as you can see in the picture I ran the query at hh:07 so its shifted slightly to the right of the hours, and the later I run the query the more they will shift to the right of the top of the hour shown in the graph, I want them to always show exactly at hh:00:00 so they look centered on the hour they occured in

Comment: Yes but it groups on the exact time as you can see in my output in the qestion so when you display this in a column graph the bar ends up offset from the hour because the column graph X axis shows 20:00 21:00 22:00 but depending on when the query runs the resulting column will end upp offset from that X axis since it groups on the exact time of query execution which you can see above is hh:40:22 meaning it will show in between 06:00 and 07:00 in the column graph which looks weird and further more if I run the query 40 minutes later the bars will shift to the to the right of the Hours in graph

Comment: I added an image to the question to try and clarify the issue, it looks like it summarizes based on the exact hour when query is run and NOT 07:00 - 08:00 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using `from`, the step is aligned to a round hour.
If you are using `from`, the step is aligned to the `from` value.

```
from bin(_startTime,1h) to _endTime
```

Comment: This works for hour but not when step is 1d from bin(_startTime,1d) to _endTime step 1d in this case for some reason its still off and starts at 0800 and shows to the right of the actual date

Comment: if your step is 1d then the bin should also be 1d: `from bin(_startTime,1d) to _endTime`

Comment: thats what I have but I think it's because its the time zone that makes it show off, the timestamp is in UTC I am looking from China so it shows 8h off, if I set my time zone to UTC then it shows correctly on top, wonder how people handle this in global deployments? when step is 1d adjusting for TZ makes little sense as 13th is always the 13th so to say

Comment: "A datetime value in Kusto is always in the UTC time zone. Displaying datetime values in other time zones is the responsibility of the user application that displays the data, not a property of the data itself."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime

Comment: I understand that and I have read the documentation but you have to agree that if I am in a different timezone and looks at a column graph by date it looks weird that my bar on the 13th looks off to the right of the date marker in the diagram,

Comment: The reference to the documentation was to clarify that ADX works only with UTC. I am not sure where is the issue now from your side - If you ingest data in UTC than the presentation of that data would be correct.

Comment: Its not really an issue but more of a weird visualisation but thats eboynd the scope of this question, I understand now the functionality thanks I really appreciate the help